# Link on site logo works only at the bottom

Tags: html, css, graphical-logo

On my site the logo will only link at the bottom. I believe this is because the navigation stops it from linking.

My site is [chattrd.com/htdocs](http://chattrd.com/htdocs).

I have tried putting the `<div>` inside the `<a>` tags, and putting half of the `<div>` in the `<a>` tags. Neither of these solutions worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest ways:

- Remove `position: relative` from

  ```
  .navigation-primary_right {
      position: relative;
      text-align: right;
  }
  ```

Or

- Insert `z-index:1` into

  ```
  .header_brand {
      position: absolute;
  }
  ```

But I recommend you not to use `position:absolute`. I would use instead something like

```
.header_brand {
    float: left;
}
.header-primary_container {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative; /* Optional */
}
```